# How do I translate and scale points within a bounding box?

Tags: algorithm, math, point, pseudocode, bounding-box

I have a number of points *P* of the form `(x, y)` where `x,y` are real numbers. I want to translate and scale all these points within a bounding box (rectangle) which begins at the point `(0,0)` (top left) and extends to the point `(1000, 1000)` (bottom right).

Why is it that the following algorithm does not produce points in that bounding box?

```
for Point p in P:
    max = greatest(p.x, p.y, max)

scale = 1000 / max
for Point p in P:
    p.x = (p.x - 500) * scale + 500
    p.y = (p.y - 500) * scale + 500
```

I fear that this won't work when `p.x` or `p.y` is a negative number.

I would also like to maintain the "shape" of the points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Find all of yMin, yMax, xMin, xMax, xDelta = xMax-xMin and yDelta = yMax-yMin for your set of points.
2. Set max = greatest(xDelta,yDelta).
3. Foreach Point p set p.X = (p.X - xMin) * scale and p.Y = (p.Y - yMin) * scale